# WindowLeaked from library module

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-module

I'm moving pieces of my app into a library module for code sharing.  From what I've read you can put anything and everything in a library, but I'm suddenly getting WindowLeaked errors any time I try to open a dialog from the library code.  I didn't find anything on the web about it.  Does anyone know if there's something different you need to do to open dialogs from a library module, or if it just isn't supported?  For example, because someone always wants to see code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
// ...set up the dialog...
final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Comment: Where are you calling the Dialog?

Comment: In a utility class.  The Context used in is an Activity.

Comment: Post the part where the Dialog is been used in the utility class.

Comment: If I understand you, that code is posted above.  If you mean something else, could you clarify?

Comment: What I meant is the function that's triggering the above code.

Comment: It's not very interesting.  From an Activity in the app module (not the library): `dialogUtils.reportError(this, R.string.error_referral_code);`  which goes through a chain of method calls to end up with the code I posted in the question.

Comment: I restarted the whole project of converting to a library module and dialogs are working now so I guess this one will remain a mystery.